# Integrate Tapestry Archetype Catalog in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, tapestry

I'm in eclipse, with the embedded Maven, trying to import a "Remote Archetype Catalog" from the adress "http://tapestry.apache.org" in the Preferences.
But some seconds after clicking "OK" it says "Remote Catalog is empty".

What am I doing wrong ? How can I import a Catalog in Eclipse-maven ?

Comment: try using this url for downloading catalogs https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try manualy with the console with mvn command like in http://tapestry.apache.org/getting-started.html

You may upgrade your eclipse IDE:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390183
or use www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/add-archetype-dialog.html